# In Swift how do I declare a reference to a global pointer that's declared in objective-c code?

Tags: cocoa-touch, swift2

My App is objective-c origin, with all new files being Swift.  My main.m file has:

```
ConfigMgr* configMgr;
```

All my objective-c (.m) files have:

```
extern ConfigMgr* configMgr;
```

It's a global pointer because everyone needs to access some info about the configuration.  (It's my only global and I make no apology for it.)  So what do I add to my Swift files to be able to access this instance of this object as well, by using the global, not passing a pointer to every .swift file?  (My main concern is to make sure I don't end up instantiating another ConfigMgr object.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the interface of the `ConfigMgr` class is declared in `ConfigMgr.h`, include the following in the bridging header:

```
#import "ConfigMgr.h"
extern ConfigMgr* configMgr;
```

You should be good to go!